# I'm new to confluence and I have a task

Tags: jira, confluence, jira-agile, confluence-macros

I am a new user of confluence, I participate in an workflow in witch customer support receives bugs, I report them to a central team of developers. Now, the thing is I am trying to create a way for the customer support team to have more visibility on the issues that I report, as in to quickly find out the status of a certain issues. What I have in mind is a confluence page consisting of a table of the issues extracted from Jira but I am having trouble reaching the exact end product that I have in mind. For example is there a way for me to make a column to this table so I can add comments for some issues? or can I categorize the issues by which pack of developers are they assigned to. Mainly I want to know if there is an alternative way of going about my situation and I don't see it because of my lack of experience.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than adding comments in Confluence I would suggest you instead add them to the Jira tickets and then display them on Confluence.

The Jira Issues macro allows you to chose the fields you display. You could, for example, add a 'Confluence comment' custom field to your Jira tickets and make sure this is shown in Confluence.

As for categorizing issues, this is best done by using filters. The approach would be as follows:

- Decide what categories you want
- Create a filter for each category
- Use the Jira Issues macro multiple times, once for each of the filters